# textile and maruku problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, textile, maruku

I've developed custom filters for HAML (http://github.com/alec-c4/cb-haml-filters) and have a small problem with textile and maruku. Maybe you can help me with this

1. Problem with textile
   with code

   ```
     %h2 Textile test
     :cbtextile
       h4. YouTube video
        http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0_IXrjqKbE4&feature=player_embedded
   ```

after parsing i see embeded youtube video inside h4 tag (there are 1 empty line between h4. and http://youtube... i mean \n\n). But on TWO empty lines (\n\n\n) - all renders correctly. In markdown - all html renders fine.

2. Maruku.
   all is ok, but scribd filter causes error

   REXML could not parse this XML/HTML: